# How to hide views in android when android app is backgrounded (not to stop android to take snapshot when backgrounded)

Tags: android

I want to hide my views when my app is backgrounded. For e.g. I want to hide this "Live Debug Mode" textview when my app is backgrounded.

[image: Consider this backgrounded app for e.g.]

Comment: explain more please

Comment: Android doesn't have the concept of "minimizing", just putting to the background, so I don't understand... And *where* does it show the views?

Comment: if your app is "minimized" how can you see it?

Comment: What do you mean by minimizing an app? Please attach a picture of your minimized app to get your question more clear.

Comment: @cricket_007, I do not believe this is a duplicate question. This question is specifically related to hiding a portion of the screen before a screenshot is taken, not disabling the screenshot altogether.

Comment: @Krejko, you got what I meant to say.

Comment: @Krejko I flagged as unclear probably

Answer (score 7):

Add the following code to your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    //...rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer does not work. I thought about deleting the answer, but then thought it would better serve as information to anyone searching this in the future. I am not sure why it doesn't work. Intuitively to me, it should.

---

Use the `onPause` lifecycle method to set the views you need hidden to either invisible or gone using `setVisibility()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I tried.... and it does not work.

Comment: @OmkarAmberkar How about that. You're right. My mistake.

Comment: my guess is that the thumbnail cache is created before `onPause` is called

Comment: agreed, that is what I could get from its behavior